# When the transaction will be committed?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

I need some clarification regarding Spring transation.
In `ClassA` I am creating a declaritive transaction. From `ClassA` I am calling `method1()` of `ClassB`.
`ClassB` is having `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)` annotation in classs level.
In `method1()` I am doing a save operation.

My question is, when that data will be committed ? Will it be committed while control will come out from 
`method1()`? or in `ClassA` where we are committing the transaction manually ?.

Code:

**ClassA**

```
class ClassA {

    void myMethod() {
        TransactionStatus status = null;
        DefaultTransactionDefinition def =
                new DefaultTransactionDefinition(TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW);
        def.setTimeout(contentFileProcessingConfigBean.getFileCopyTransactionTimeout());
        status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);

        b.method1();

        if (status != null) {
            transactionManager.commit(status);
        }
    }

}
```

**ClassB**

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
class ClassB {

void method1() {

//doing save operation

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably after `B.method1()` finishes the aspect which is wrapping the call to `@Transactional` (visible in the stack trace) will commit the transaction. However this will depend on:

- Are `A` and `B` are both Spring beans?
- Is the same `transactionManager` bean used by transactions in `A` and `B`?
- Maybe if `A` is written using [`TransactionTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) instead of plain `TransactionManager` object.

Mixing the manual and declarative transaction management is not recommended as you have to guess. I guess it will come to `transactionManager` which you are not showing.

Comment: So u r telling that it will be committed n following line ?
`transactionManager.commit(status);`

Comment: @Rehman I'd guess it will be just after `b.method1();` finishes execution. It's a guess though, I'd be happy if you can prove me wrong with a test. You have omitted a lot of code e.g. are `A` and `B` spring beans?

Comment: A and B both are spring beans. B is not using any transactionManager. Its having class level Transactional annotation.

Comment: `B` is using `@Transactional` with default `transactionManager` attribute value (check the annotation source code). There is always a transaction manager for declarative transactions but it's impossible to tell what it is without seeing your full Spring context.

Comment: Hmm. I will have a look. My understanding was also in the same line as you have mentioned in your answer. 
But when I see the log this theory is not fitting into that. In my application one thread updating the value
and coming out from that method method1(). Later when other thread is fetching the data its getting old record, not 
the latest one.

Comment: @Rehman It could be that if `transactionManager` bean is shared between declarative and programmatic transaction they will work together. This  case is not described in the docs and I'd never recommend to mix these two together, it's a nightrmare to debug.